# My links that should use my hooks to show/hide components are not working as expected

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have the following component that should load two other components depending on a button click.

My GameDungeon component should load when I click the "DungeonPage" link and it should also hide the "GameCharacter" component.

Likewise, but reversed for the "CharacterPage" button.

However, when I click either button, nothing happens.  No change, no loading, and also no errors.

So I'm not sure where to go from here.

I followed along a few React & React Hooks tutorials, but I just can't get this to work.

Here's my code:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import GameDungeon from "../App";
import GameCharacter from "../Character/App";

const Admin = () => {

    const [showDungeon, setDungeon] = useState(false);
    const [showCharacter, setCharacter] = useState(false);

    const handleCharacterClick = e => { setDungeon(false) && setCharacter(true) };
    const handleDungeonClick = e => { setCharacter(false) && setDungeon(true) };

    return (
        <div className="admin">
            <nav>
                <div>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <a id="DungeonPage" href="#" onClick={ () => handleDungeonClick}>Game Dungeon</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a id="CharacterPage" href="#" onClick={ () => handleCharacterClick}>Game Character</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </nav>  

            <div>
                {showDungeon && <GameDungeon />}
            </div>
            <div>
                {showCharacter && <GameCharacter />}
            </div>
        </div>

    );
}
```

Is there anything I'm missing or doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pass the callback function directly as prop. Also, wrap the callback with the `useCallback` hook for better performance.

```
import React, { useState, useCallback } from "react";
import GameDungeon from "../App";
import GameCharacter from "../Character/App";

const Admin = () => {

    const [showDungeon, setDungeon] = useState(false);
    const [showCharacter, setCharacter] = useState(false);

    const handleCharacterClick = useCallback(e => setDungeon(false) || setCharacter(true));
    const handleDungeonClick = useCallback(e => setCharacter(false) || setDungeon(true));

    return (
        <div className="admin">
            <nav>
                <div>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <a id="DungeonPage" href="#" onClick={handleDungeonClick}>Game Dungeon</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a id="CharacterPage" href="#" onClick={handleCharacterClick}>Game Character</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </nav>  

            <div>
                {showDungeon && <GameDungeon />}
            </div>
            <div>
                {showCharacter && <GameCharacter />}
            </div>
        </div>

    );
}
```

Comment: I added the useCallback function to both but still nothing happens.  No errors though either.

Comment: The problem is the callback. `setDungeon` and `setCharacter`returns void. In order to run both functions replace `&&` by `||` or use a function with multiple lines.

Answer (score 1):

There are couple of issues with your code. What you can do to get around this problem is by making following changes:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

import GameDungeon from "../App";
import GameCharacter from "../Character/App";

function Admin(){
    const [showDungeon, setDungeon] = useState(false);
    const [showCharacter, setCharacter] = useState(false);

    function handleCharacterClick(){ 
      setDungeon(false); 
      setCharacter(true);
    }

    function handleDungeonClick() { 
     setCharacter(false);
     setDungeon(true); 
    }

    return (
        <div className="admin">
            <nav>
                <div>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <a id="DungeonPage" href="#" onClick={handleDungeonClick}>Game Dungeon</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a id="CharacterPage" href="#" onClick={handleCharacterClick}>Game Character</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </nav>  

            <div>
                {!!showDungeon && <GameDungeon />}
            </div>
            <div>
                {!!showCharacter && <GameCharacter />}
            </div>
        </div>

    );
}
```